# Make Facebook comments on Facebook page show up on my Drupal site

Tags: 7

Using Drupal 7. I post some stories on Facebook and receive a lot of comments. I want these comments to also show up on the article page on my drupal site, not just on the Facebook page inside facebook. That is, when users comment on the post inside Facebook, i want the comment to show on the article page on my drupal website. Any ideas in getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [Facebook Comments Social Plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments) Module

> Implement Facebook commenting with settings on the level of both
>   content type and node. This module comes with a Facebook Comments
>   block so you can have comments anywhere on your site.

There are another modules which support your functionalities -> [FB Comments Box](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments_box)

> This module gives your site the ability of using Facebook's Comments
>   Box social plugin, i.e. comments on your site powered by Facebook. It
>   provides an easy way to configure Facebook Comments parameters (like
>   theme, administrators, number of posts, node types to attach to) and
>   then exposes the generated code as a block for you to insert into a
>   region of your choice. This module is intended for anyone who wants to
>   put Facebook Comments on their Drupal site in addition to or instead
>   of Drupal comments from core.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but Could you please read my requirements again? I am not looking for a module to enable people use their Facebook account to comment inside my website. I'm rather looking for a module which can pull their comments made inisde facebook back to the article page on my site. DO you think these modules still solve that requirement?